# Export an agenda in a meeting workspace

Tags: meeting-workspace, wss-3.0, excel

I have a meeting workspace with a recurring meeting. (WSS 3.0 hosted by Network Solutions)

When I export the agenda to Excel I get the previous agendas as well as the one for the selected meeting.

It is not marked as a series item and the Show Data for All Meetings option is not selected.

Is there a way to export the agenda for just a single meeting?  Or is there a better way to produce a printable agenda for distribution to people that are not on my SharePoint site?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the SharePoint Web Services for a little more control. I haven't "wrapped" all of the [Meetings Web Service operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774629.aspx) in my [jQuery Library for SharePoint Web Services (SPServices)](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) yet because no one has asked for them, but I could.

Another thought would be to use a Data View Web Part (DVWP) on a page to generate an agenda formatted any way that you want for easy printing.  You could do this on a page which doesn't use the master page if you want it to be a real "print representation".